# Kotlin - change element in a List of Strings

Tags: kotlin

```
fun main() {
    datum(datum)

}
    val datum = "Bfasld |datum=July 13, 1996 |autor="

fun datum (test: String) {
    var text : MutableList<String> = test.split("|") as MutableList<String>
    println(text.forEach{println(it)})
    val d = Datum()

    text.forEach{ it ->
        if(it.startsWith("datum")){
            var datum : String = it.substring(6)
            var neuesDatum = d.datumWandeln(datum.trim())
            it = "datum=$neuesDatum"

        }
}
```

Hello i'm new to Kotlin.

This part of the code shall take a String. Split it into parts. And then change specific parts completly.

My problem is the  "it =". I can't change the Strings of the List, because they are val. Is it possible to make them var?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `it` inside the lambda is an [implicit name of a its single parameter](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#it-implicit-name-of-a-single-parameter), it can't be reassigned.

In this case I'd recommend to:

1. Use functional style (and get rid of mutability)
2. Use [regular expression](https://regex101.com/r/JoEMPN/1) to capture specific part of the string

```kotlin
val regex = "^datum=(.*?)\\s*\$".toRegex()
val result = test
    .split("|")
    .map {
        val matchResult = regex.find(it)
        if (matchResult != null) "datum=${d.datumWandeln(matchResult.groupValues[1])}" else it
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a for loop as opposed to the functional `forEach` equivalent.

So something like this:

```
for (i in text.indices) {

    text[i] = ...
}
```

The `it` inside the lambda is just a pointer to a specific element, it can't be reassigned.

---

Note that you could also use `forEachIndexed` for the same result. However if you really want to keep to the functional style (and enforce immutability), you might want to use `map` on your original list:

```
text.map {

    if(it.startsWith("datum")) {

        ...
    }
    else {

        it
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm coming from Java and wanted to try Kotlin.

Comment: In Kotlin the preferred approach would probably be to keep your lists immutable. Then you can map into a new list, but this obviously has performance implications. If the answer is the one you're looking for, you can accept it with the tick!

Comment: Also that cast seems pretty dangerous. If the `split` implementation changes in the future you might have problems. So actually I would definitely recommend mapping it to a new list.